# Spring Boot @Aspect J logging

Tags: java, spring-mvc, spring-boot, aop

I created test Spring MVC application with REST controller. I want to apply aspects for my some method, but when this method is called nothing happen and I can't find the reason.
It is my Configuration and Application class:

```
@SpringBootApplication(scanBasePackages = "org.test")
@EnableAspectJAutoProxy
public class TestaopApplication {

public static void main(String[] args) {
    SpringApplication.run(TestaopApplication.class, args);
}
}
```

It is my aspect class:

```
@Aspect
@Component
public class Logging {

private static final Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(GreetingController.class);
@Pointcut("execution(* org.test.restspring.model.Greeting.getCreatedDate(..))")
private void getDate(){}

@Before("getDate()")
public void beforeGettingDate(){
    logger.info("Date is asked");
}

@After("getDate()")
public void afterGettingDate(){
    logger.info("Date is received");
}
```

}

It is my simple bean:

```
@Component
public class Greeting {

private long id;
private String content;
private Date created;

public Greeting() { }
public Greeting(long id, String content) {
    this.id = id;
    this.content = content;
    this.created = Calendar.getInstance().getTime();
}

public long getId() {
    return id;
}

public String getContent() {
    return content;
}

public String getCreatedDate(){
    return created.toString();
}
 }
```

It is my Controller:

```
@RestController
public class GreetingController {

private static final String template = "Hello, %s!";
private static final Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(GreetingController.class);
private final AtomicLong counter = new AtomicLong();

@RequestMapping("/greeting")
public Greeting greeting(@RequestParam(value="name", defaultValue="World") String name) {
    Greeting response = new Greeting(counter.incrementAndGet(),
            String.format(template, name));
    logger.info(response.getCreatedDate());
    return response;
}


}
```

Please help me with this problem.

Answer (score 0):

Beans created via explicit constructor call (`new Greeting(...)`) are not managed by Spring. That is why your aspect is not applied.

You can try to use prototype scope. This way Spring creates new instance of greeting bean for every request.

for bean:

```
@Component
@Scope("prototype")
public class Greeting {
```

and your controller:

```
@RestController
public class GreetingController {

private static final String template = "Hello, %s!";
private static final Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(GreetingController.class);
private final AtomicLong counter = new AtomicLong();

@Autowired
private Greeting greeting;

@RequestMapping("/greeting")
public Greeting greeting(@RequestParam(value="name", defaultValue="World") String name) {
    greeting.setId(counter.incrementAndGet());
    greeting.setContent(String.format(template, name))
    logger.info(response.getCreatedDate());
    return response;
}



}
```

Comment: I gor an error, but when I replace method with non-existent in @Pointcut(that aspect is not applied to method), I have no error. It is error::Failed to write HTTP message: org.springframework.http.converter.HttpMessageNotWritableException: Could not write content: No serializer found for class org.springframework.aop.TrueClassFilter and no properties discovered to create BeanSerializer (to avoid exception, disable SerializationFeature.FAIL_ON_EMPTY_BEANS) )

Comment: And I have getters and setters in me Greeting class.